# Where did our present regex notation originate?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, reference-request, notation, history

First question, and my apologies if it is off-topic!  [This question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/64819/74314) suggests to me I may not be totally off-base.

Where did our present regex notation originate?  I am particularly wondering how `$` came to mean "end," particularly since its most common use in the English-speaking world (as far as I know) is as a *prefix* to numbers.  I also wonder about `.` for "any".

`*` I know came directly from Kleene, and `+` seems like a logical extension of `*`, if only because they are closely related in mathematics.

I have been several pages down in a couple different Google Web and Scholar searches.  I have also looked here and on SO and softwareengineering.SE, but I can't find an answer.  I checked [Perl 6's Apocalypse 5](https://www.perl.com/pub/2002/06/04/apo5.html), but it doesn't explain how we got our present notation.  I seem to recall that Kernighan's *Software Tools* might have had some information, but I can't put my hands on a copy at the moment.  Thank you!

**Edit** Another data point - [TECO](http://almy.us/teco.html) dates from 1962, and terminated input strings with `Esc`, displayed as `$` ([source](http://web.mit.edu/~yandros/doc/craft-text-editing/Appendix-D.html)).  Unfortunately,

> the Escape character ... is written as "$" (for historical reasons, of course).

*Id.*  That considerably predates UNIX v3 (1973), but doesn't explain the then-existing "historical reasons."

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best forum for this question – perhaps stackoverflow is better.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for the feedback!  I didn't ask on SO because there's no MCVE for this question :) .  Specifically, the SO tour says that "anything not directly related to writing computer programs" is off-topic there.  Do you have any other ideas for where I could ask?  Much appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest that this might have a place in this forum. One  question is whether this use of the "$" symbol has an origin in the academic/theoretical literature (e.g.: regular events) that predates Ken Thompson's use of it in the *ed* text editor circa 1970.

Comment: Also + is in use in algebra, just as * is, this was not invented for regular expressions. A^* is the free monoid, A^+ the free semigroup over the set A.

Comment: This notation was probably first introduced in `ed` in UNIX V3. See the story of the creation of `grep` by Ken Thompson on March 3, 1973 from Doug McIlroy account in [Netizens](http://www.columbia.edu/~hauben/Book_Anniversary/Netizens%20An%20Anthology%20part%20II.pdf) and an account of history of grep line anchor metacharacters in "Mastring Regular Expressions" by Jeffrey Friedl.

Comment: I don't think this is a computer science question. The regular expressions used by software packages and programming languages are fundamentally different from the ones used in computer science. For example, in CS, we always compare the whole string against the regular expression whereas, in software systems, we usually have to use something like `^...$` to force comparison against the whole string, rather than any substring. I think a question about CS notation would be fine, but this isn't a question about CS notation.